# How to enhance scans of golden emboss?

Tags: image-processing

I am looking for smooth way to enhance scans of golden emboss on. For now it takes sometimes hours to select out the golden part and then manipulate into suitable color. But I hope to learn some more neat way to do it.

So here I provide 2 sample images, one before and other after:

[image: image after scan]

[image: image with enhanced golden emboss]

So, after lot of annoying work to select out the golden part from background it still looks out clumsy. So, how it might work out smoothly? Is there some tutorial for that?

Basicly, what I did now?

1. made duplicate layer of background
2. selected and erased background on duplicate layer with different tools (most work of which I'd like to get rid of)
3. selected background and inverted selection
4. feathered selection 5px
5. with Colorize got it to some goldish tone
6. slide layer opacity ca 60%

Comment: This is a sensoring problem. The damage is done in the scanner. Photographees know a lot about these things. Its not really a computer graphics problem as a image capture problem. How to use software is out of scope.

Comment: @joojaa Maybe you have idea where to look out for help? Tried to find desktop publishing and scanning and graphic design forums, but no luck so far.

Comment: Well there is [GD.Se](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)